# Directory Opus and Autohotkey working together

Tags: autohotkey

I have an autohotkey script which loops through all files which are dragged onto its icon.

The filenames are processed inside the loop using RegEx, and then FILEMOVEd into a new name.

The script works perfectly when files are dragged onto the icon.

But when I place the script into a Directory Opus button, followed by {filepath$} (which is supposed to send all selected files to the script), multiple instances of the script are launched, and usually some of the items I selected are ignored (not processed). Here's the code.

```
Loop %0%
{ 
   Path := %A_Index%
    Loop %Path%, 1
    LongPath = %A_LoopFileLongPath%    
   SplitPath LongPath, OutFileName, OutDir, OutExtension, OutNameNoExt, OutDrive 

...

FileMove, %LongPath%, %OutDir%/%OutNameNoExt%_%FormatCode%.%OutExtension%
}
exitapp
```

Comment: Yes please share your code first.

Comment: Apart from the missing brackets for the second loop, I see no problem. The section where you start with "But when I put the path of the script into a Directory Opus button..." is not clear to me. Could you try to describe this differently / more elaborately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use **{filepath$}**, Directory Opus will run the command once per file, one file at a time. It is for commands which can only accept a single file at a time.

To pass all the filepaths at once, on a single command-line, use **{allfilepath$}**